# Not able to get value form JsonNode in java

Tags: java, json

I have a json string as below :

```
"{\"event\":\"PremiumAdsViews\",\"data\":{\"id\":12,\"category_id\":12,\"category_gid\":11,\"adStyle\":\"T\"}}"
```

When I am trying to convert it into JsonNode, I get the JsonNode as below and I am not able to access any value from get method of JsonNode

```
{"_value":"{\"event\":\"PremiumAdsViews\",\"data\":{\"id\":12,\"category_id\":12,\"category_gid\":11,\"adStyle\":\"T\"}}"}
```

How can we parse the json string with double quotes on rear end into pure jsonNode ?

Comment: How exactly do you convert it into the JsonNode?

Answer (score 1):

```
 JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
 JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(tmpStr);
 System.out.println("NodeValue:" + (String) jsonObject.get("event"));
```

you can try this